# Is this Half-dragon Quaggoth boss monster balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, monster-design

This is going to be an early boss for my upcoming campaign. I have 7 5th-level player characters, and this fight is meant to challenge them quite a bit. There will also be a few minions.

The story is that this quaggoth found a dying dryad and consumed her heart, this made him a sorcerer as well as giving him some druid magic. Then the cult of the dragon found him and made him a half dragon. If the players don't kill him I plan on making him an NPC later on.

I would like to know if this monster is ready to be thrown at my players, if it is too overpowered or underpowered at its current challenge rating, and what I can do to fix any balancing problems found in the stats of this monster.

---

> ### Treill
>
> *Half-dragon Quaggoth Thonot (4th-level sorcerer)*
>
> **Armor Class:** 16 (permanent Barkskin)
>
> **Hit points:** 48
>
> **Str** (16; +3) **Dex** (12; +1) **Con** (16; +3) **Int** (8; -1) **Wis** (12; +1) **Cha** (14; +2)
>
> **Saving Throws:** Str +6, Con +6
>
> **Senses**: Treill has *blindsight* out to 10 ft, and *darkvision* out to 180 ft.
>
> **Challenge:** 7
>
> ***Wounded Fury***. While he has 10 hit points or fewer, Treill has advantage on attack rolls. In addition, he deals an extra 7 (2d6) damage to any target he hits with a melee attack.
>
> ***Lightning resistance.***
>
> ***Multiattack***. The quaggoth makes two claw attacks.
>
> ***Claw Attack.*** *Melee Weapon Attack*: + 5 to hit, reach 5 ft., 1 target. *Hit:* 5 (1d6 + 3) slashing damage.
>
> ***Lightning breath*** Recharge (5-6). Treill can use his action to exhale destructive energy. Each creature in a in a 5 by 30 ft. line must make a Dexterity saving throw or take 24 (7d6) lightning damage, or half as much on a successful save.
>
> ***Spellcasting***. Treill is a 4th-level caster; his casting ability is Charisma. Spell save DC 13; +5 to hit with spell attacks.
>
> Cantrips (at will) *fire bolt, sword burst, poison spray, predestination, toll the dead.*
>
> 1st level (3 slots): *color spray, magic missile, shield.*
>
> 2nd level (2 slots): *invisibility, spider climb.*
>
> ***Innate spellcasting***. Thonot DC 12. +4 to hit.
>
> At will: *mage hand, feather fall.*
>
> 1/day: *Cure wounds, enlarge/reduce, heat metal, mirror image.*
>
> ***Magic initiate (druid)***. DC 12, +4 to hit with spell attacks.
>
> Cantrips: *Thorn whip, druidcraft*
>
> 1/day: *healing word*

Comment: Please don't edit your post to change the creature's stats after people have answered, invalidating existing answers. Instead, make a new post asking if the revised stats are balanced, if needed. Relevant metas: [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question), [Can we develop a system to avoid/discourage subsequent homebrew critique question edits?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/can-we-develop-a-system-to-avoid-discourage-subsequent-homebrew-critique-questio)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92718/discussion-on-question-by-josiah-riggan-is-this-half-dragon-quaggoth-boss-monste).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## This would not be a real challenge for *3* characters

Your creature is about CR2. 3 moderately optimizer characters would rip it apart in 2 rounds. Against 7, it should not last a round.

### How it should look

You say you want to challenge your players, this sounds like at least a Hard encounter, 5250 XP for 7 players. For a single creature it is CR9.

DMG says (page 274), such a creature should have **AC 16, attack bonus 7, HP 191-205, damage 57-62**.
Your's is very far behind everything but AC. On damage and HP it is downright crippled, a CR1 is supposed to have more HP.

Answer (score 4):

No, this monster is much too weak for CR7.

The guidelines tell us that a CR7 monster is expected to have AC 15 and 161-175hp, with 45-50 damage per round (averaged over three rounds) at +6 to hit (or DC15 save). Of course individual monsters will vary, but your monster has far too few hit points and also does not deal enough damage.

[There's a table in the DMG (p. 274) with this information.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#MonsterStatisticsbyChallengeRating)